# Showing records within a time of day inside a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I feel like I'm being stupid with this one and it may even come to me after a sleep and a coffee tomorrow

I want to filter records within a date range to night shift or day shift using a parameter, the day shift parameter works fine but I can't quite wrap my head around the night shift one as it crosses two days (the shift is from 6pm to 5am)

Here's what I have at the moment, which wont show any records for 'Nights'.. I understand why it doesn't but I can't think how it should be written :)

```
AND
(
(@shift = 'Nights' AND DATEPART(hh,[PostingDate]) >= 17 AND DATEPART(hh,[PostingDate]) <= 6)
or (@shift = 'Days' AND DATEPART(hh,[PostingDate]) >= 6 AND DATEPART(hh,[PostingDate]) <= 17)
)
```

Comment: Please add some more info, what is the error you're getting or the expected result your not getting, maybe also add more db info and some data to test. Please read creating [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question for us to be able to help you along with the database server your using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Datepart(HH, PostingDate)` is always going to be the same value for any given row, so it will never be both >=17 and <= 6.  You probably want to use `OR` or `NOT BETWEEN.`

For example:

```
(@shift = 'Nights' 
    AND DATEPART(hh,[PostingDate]) NOT BETWEEN 6 and 17)
or (@shift = 'Days' 
    AND DATEPART(hh,[PostingDate]) BETWEEN 6 and 17)
```

Comment: Thanks! so simple yet I couldn't see it

Comment: @Dave glad this helped!  If it solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Done, only took me 3 months :)